# Getting the docstring from a function

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def my_func():
    """My docstring is both funny and informative"""
    pass
```

How do I get access to the docstring?

Comment: Note that running Python with -OO strips out docstrings.  If you intend to distribute your code to others, keep in mind that they may run it that way.  It will make those people really really unhappy if your code relies on docstrings, but doesn't catch the case where they don't exist.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Interactively, you can display it with

```
help(my_func)
```

Or from code you can retrieve it with (surround it with `print(.)` to get a formatted output):

```
my_func.__doc__
```

Comment: BTW: This technique works with builtin functions as well as modules and classes (test help() with objects too - might also work). This makes your python shell an interactive help shell!

Comment: On the ipython prompt, you can do my_func?? and it would show the docstring as well.

Comment: help(func) gives a readable output while func.__doc__ gives a inline output. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Mr.UnnormalizedPosterior try `print(func.__doc__)`; I find it more useful while in the CLI, easy to go back to the func's signature when needed.

Answer (score 107):

You can also use [`inspect.getdoc`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getdoc). It cleans up the `__doc__` by normalizing tabs to spaces and left shifting the doc body to remove common leading spaces.

Comment: It cleans it up a bit, but you still get newlines at the original e.g. 80 characters, when the text needs to be printed in a terminal that is wider, e.g. 120 characters. Is there a way to really clean up the `__doc__` ?

Comment: @xApple The docstring can generally contain lists or blocks of code - things that you want to keep formatted by newlines. If you still want to remove all the newlines in the string, then just remove them, using the [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method.

Answer (score 13):

On ipython or jupyter notebook, you can use all the above mentioned ways, but i go with

```
my_func?
```

or

```
?my_func
```

for quick summary of both method signature and docstring.

I avoid using

```
my_func??
```

(as commented by @rohan) for docstring and use it only to check the source code

Answer (score -2):

```
import ast
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1], "r") #filename input
module = ast.parse(f.read())
class_definitions = [node for node in module.body if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef)]
method_definitions = []
for class_def in class_definitions:
        print(class_def.name)
        print(ast.get_docstring(class_def))
        function_definitions = [node for node in class_def.body if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef)]
        for f in function_definitions:
                print('\t---')
                print('\t'+f.name)
                print('\t---')
                print('\t'+'\t'.join(ast.get_docstring(f).splitlines(True)))
        print('----')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is an interesting answer but it'd be better if you explained a little bit about what this code does and why you'd choose it instead of one of the established answers?