# python: how to get information about a function?

Tags: python, function, methods

When information about a type is needed you can use:

```
my_list = []
dir(my_list)
```

gets:

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

or:

```
dir(my_list)[36:]
```

gets:

```
['append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

Now, in the documentation of Python information can be found about these functions, but I would like to get info about these functions in the terminal/command-line.
How should this be done?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

In python: `help(my_list.append)` for example, will give you the docstring of the function.

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> help(my_list.append)

    Help on built-in function append:

    append(...)
        L.append(object) -- append object to end
```

Comment: Where does it get the info from though?

Comment: @Pithikos more specifically – a lot of it is generated automatically based on declarations – but the details however are generated from comments that follow the docstring format (i.e. triple quotes, first-line after declaration).  You can apply it to pretty much anything that is in the namespace; modules, classes, functions, etc.

Comment: The questions seems to be asking, how can I get this info in a variable... I may have misinterpreted, but that's my particular need. I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/713143/93910

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
help(my_list)
```

to get built-in help messages.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pydoc`.

Open your terminal and type `python -m pydoc list.append`

The advantage of `pydoc` over `help()` is that you do not have to import a module to look at its help text.
For instance `python -m pydoc random.randint`.

Also you can start an HTTP server to interactively browse documentation by typing `python -m pydoc -b` (python 3)

For more information `python -m pydoc`

Comment: wat does it means to use pydoc?  What format should be applied?

Answer (score 3):

`help(functionname)` 
Can use this to print the Additional Info About the function you specified in help(..)

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
help(list.append)
```

if you're generally poking around.