# Where does help() find the info in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, helper, built-in

I discovered the built-in `help()` recently that prints some information for a module, function, method, class, etc. But where exactly does it find the information it shows? [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) don't give a single hint about this.

```
>>> import base64
>>> help(base64)
Help on module base64:

NAME
    base64 - RFC 3548: Base16, Base32, Base64 Data Encodings

FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py
..
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430020/python-how-to-get-information-about-a-function

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/listing-all-functions-in-a-python-module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply do, `help(help)`, you will get

```
Help on _Helper in module site object:

class _Helper(__builtin__.object)
 |  Define the builtin 'help'.
 |  This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
 |  
 |  __repr__(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

basically, `help` gets its input from `pydoc.help`. Quoting, [`pydoc` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc),

> **For modules, classes, functions and methods, the displayed documentation is derived from the docstring (i.e. the `__doc__` attribute) of the object, and recursively of its documentable members. If there is no docstring, `pydoc` tries to obtain a description from the block of comment lines just above the definition of the class, function or method in the source file, or at the top of the module** (see `inspect.getcomments()`).
>
> The built-in function `help()` invokes the online help system in the interactive interpreter, which uses `pydoc` to generate its documentation as text on the console.

---

> But where exactly does it find the information it shows?

The quoted bold text above answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

It is in `site.py`, if you use `help.__class__` you will see it is `site._Helper` which is just  a wrapper around `pydoc.help` :

```
In [1]: help.__class__
Out[1]: site._Helper
```

`_Helper` class from site.py:

```
class _Helper(object):
    """Define the builtin 'help'.
    This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).

    """

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Type help() for interactive help, " \
               "or help(object) for help about object."
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        import pydoc
        return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)

def sethelper():
    __builtin__.help = _Helper()
```

`help(object)` is equivalent to `__builtin__.help(object)` which passes the object to `pydoc.help`.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the following structure

> C (directory)
>   --> __init__.py (file in this directory)

Then write the following into `__init__.py`

```
'''Some help'''
```

And run `help(C)`. You'll be shown the following

```
Help on package C:

NAME
   C - Some help

FILE
   /C/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
```

In that case `help()` gets the help from the docstring (the one between three `'`'s)

Comment: You can use a `\\` to escape the __ italicizes text problem -> \_\_init__.py

Comment: I often find myself writing `__init__.py` with backticks which also fixes this.