# What would be the equivalent of help(function()) in python and ?function() in R, in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm new to rust and am trying to find out more about functions, structs, methods, etc. as I work on a project with external crates. I'm reading the documentation as I go which is sufficient but slow, as I'm used to something similar to getting [Information on a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430020/python-how-to-get-information-about-a-function) etc. I see that there is debugging, but I was wondering what general methods are out there to finding information on structs methods etc. aside from 'read the manual' or 'look at compiler errors'

Comment: `cargo doc` will build a local copy of every crate doc used by your project. You can read it with any browser or with a some IDEs with Rust integration, such as VS-Code.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I generally keep tabs to https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html and https://docs.rs/ open. Of course, you likely have already considered those options.

As suggested by rodrigo@, you can run `cargo doc --open` to locally generate crate documentation for your project. The `--open` option will attempt to open the webpage for the documentaion in your preferred browser. (On macOS, this seems do work okay.) The webpage will be at something like `<project-root>/target/doc/<project name>/ index.html`.

Another alternative is to install [rust-analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/) which will run an LSP server for Rust. This server can be integrated with many different IDEs or Editor to quickly show documentation or even jump to the implementation of a function. For example, I setup [lsp-ui](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-ui) for Emacs a few weeks ago and have found the `lsp-ui-doc-show` and `lsp-ui-peek-find-definitions` to be very helpful for those purposes.

Hopefully some of this advice helps! =]

**Aside:** It's worth noting that Python and R are interpeted languages, and so have CLI-like environments where you can run something like a help function. Rust is however *not* an interpreted language, so you're not likely to find something very close to what you see in Python and R with respect to "help" functions.

Comment: FWIW if your search engine is duckduckgo it has bang patterns for many rust sites. `!rust <term>` will automatically look for the term on doc.rust-lang.org. `!docsrs` will search on docs.rs (but just the package names so less useful).