# How to detect which values are allowable in a parameter grid?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parameter-passing, cross-validation

I have started working on a project wherein I need to detect **trainable** parameters for a given scikit-learn estimator, and if possible, to find allowable values for categorical variables (and reasonable intervals for continuous ones).

I can fetch a dictionary with parameters using`estimator.get_params()`and then set a value using`estimator.set_params(**{'var1':val1, 'var2':val2})`, and so on.

For example, for a KNN-classifier we have the following dict of params:
`{'metric': 'minkowski', 'algorithm': 'auto', 'n_neighbors': 10, 'n_jobs': 1, 'p': 2, 'metric_params': None, 'weights': 'uniform', 'leaf_size': 30}`.

Now, I can using the types of the values to infer which are categorical (`str` types), continuous (`float`), discrete (`int`) and so on. One possibly related problem is parameters for which the default is set to `NoneType`, but I might just not touch these anyway, for a good reason.

The challenge now becomes to infer and define a parameter grid for use in e.g. `RandomizedSearchCV`. For discrete and continuous variables the problem is tractable using e.g. a combination of `try`-`except` blocks together with the scipy.stats module, possible restricting the interval to lie in the "vicinity" around the default value (but at the same time being careful to not set e.g. `n_jobs` to some crazy value -- that might need to be hard-coded in, or explicitly set later). If you have experience with something similar, and have some tips/tricks up your sleeve, I would love to hear about them.

But the real problem now is: how to infer for e.g. `algorithm` that the allowable values actually are`{‘auto’, ‘ball_tree’, ‘kd_tree’, ‘brute’}`??

I have just started looking into the problem, and perhaps we can parse the error message we get if we try to set it to some un-allowable value? I am on the look out for good ideas here, as I want to avoid having to do this manually (I will if I have to, but it seems rather inelegant...)

Comment: Note to self: This might be a very difficult/unsolvable problem. I've poked around in the api and source code, and looked at how e.g. auto-sklearn solves this. It seems that a manual (hard coded) solution is the way to go for now.

Comment: Interesting problem you've got there. Aside from [parsing the signature and default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677185/how-can-i-read-a-functions-signature-including-default-argument-values) I guess I would try parsing scikit-learn's docstring like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713138/getting-the-docstring-from-a-function). Another thing to try would be to parse the stringified function, e.g. `__init__` of the estimator but that is a - messy- long shot since I don't see any checks being done there&there is a whole hierarchy you might have to look at.

Comment: Hello! Glad you find the theme interesting. Yes, that was/is one of the options I considered/am considering (parsing the doc). But what worries me, is consistency in the way the docstrings are written, and there are no enforced conventions (but I may be wrong though) that may be taken advantage of. I might just spend a little bit of time implementing a parser and test it on a bunch of docstrings...

Comment: Yes, after looking at some of the docstrings I realize that unfortunately it won't be an easy task. There is some consistency but not enough to make this easy. Good luck! Let us know how this works out!

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this thread open and report back any progress. Have a good weekend!

Comment: Thanks! You too!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the particular example I was looking at, however, it doesn't generalize well to other doc-strings as there is no set convention wrt how they are written for each estimator in sklearn.

Therefore, I post my "solution" so that others can take over and possibly improve on it. See the following snippet:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
doc = knn.__doc__ # Get the doc string
#from sklearn.svm import SVC
#svc = SVC()
#doc = svc.__doc__
pattern = "([a-zA-Z_]+\s:\s)|(-\s*)'([a-zA-Z_]+)'" # Define search pattern
re.compile(pattern)
matches = re.findall(pattern, doc)

clf_params = {}
previous_param = ''
for param, _, value in matches:
    if ":" in param and param[-4]!="_": # 'Hack-y'
        if param not in clf_params.keys():
            clf_params[param] = list()
            previous_param = param
        else:
            if len(value)>0:
                clf_params[previous_param].append(value)
pprint(clf_params)
```

This snippet prints

```
{'algorithm : ': ['ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute', 'auto'],
 'leaf_size : ': [],
 'metric : ': [],
 'metric_params : ': [],
 'n_jobs : ': [],
 'n_neighbors : ': [],
 'p : ': [],
 'weights : ': ['uniform', 'distance']}
```

Which is correct.

However, if we repeat the same procedure for `SVC().__doc__` we will see that it fails.

I hope **somebody** finds this somewhat useful.

Comment: This is really hack-y, and it's sad I find this nearly three years as barren as it was in '17. Bummer.

Comment: Ok, here's my attempt to get all this from the docstring:
str(Algorithm().__doc__).split('Parameters\n    ----------\n')[1].split('\n\n    Attributes\n')[0].replace('\n        ', '\n')

This does not create a dictionary, but is simple enough to extract just the explained "Parameters" section from the docstring, which has all of the params explained and have all their listed possible/expected/accepted value inputs, which are nicely indented by one, tab, and now all that is left is to get just the indented rows from this string, which I am sure we can manage.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to get all this from the docstring (LinearSVC as the example algorithm), which was aided greatly by `splitlines()`:

```
liner = str(LinearSVC().__doc__).split('Parameters\n    ----------\n')[1].split('\n\n    Attributes\n')[0].replace('\n        ', '\n').splitlines()
```

This does not create a dictionary, but is simple enough to extract just the explained "Parameters" section from the docstring, which has all of the params explained and have all their listed possible/expected/accepted value inputs, which are nicely indented by one, tab, and now we can use a simple loop with a conditional, using " : " as our anchor to identify the lines of **possible/expected/accepted value inputs**:

```
for i in liner:
   ...:     if " : " in i: #<<< the key is to use " : " as our anchor
   ...:         print(i)
```

The end result, prints out to:

```
    penalty : str, 'l1' or 'l2' (default='l2')
    loss : str, 'hinge' or 'squared_hinge' (default='squared_hinge')
    dual : bool, (default=True)
    tol : float, optional (default=1e-4)
    C : float, optional (default=1.0)
    multi_class : str, 'ovr' or 'crammer_singer' (default='ovr')
    fit_intercept : bool, optional (default=True)
    intercept_scaling : float, optional (default=1)
    class_weight : {dict, 'balanced'}, optional
    verbose : int, (default=0)
    random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional (default=None)
    max_iter : int, (default=1000)
```

So glad I can share, and if anyone else needs the full docstring parameter printout, just use:

```
print(str(LinearSVC().__doc__).split('Parameters\n    ----------\n')[1].split('\n\n    Attributes\n')[0].replace('\n        ', '\n'))
```

**EDIT:**
If this is not intended to print out - the best way to have it as a string object is using a list comprehension, but it requires some ugly replaces, because there is *extensive* notation in the docstring:

```
docstring_short = str([i for i in liner.splitlines() if " : " in i]).replace('["    ', '').replace('    ', ',\n').replace('", "', '').replace('", \'', '').replace("', '", '').replace("', \"", '').replace(']', '')
```