# Extract docstring from a python function

Tags: python

I want to extract a docstring from every function in a python module.
Thought, help does the intended action, It would print out a lot of extra stuff which I do not need. I have tried .__ doc__ as well. However, Even that does print out a lot of stuff and also print \n and \t.

eg.

```
def Foo():
"""
This is
a multiline
comment
"""
    pass:
```

I want something which will give me only the comment as a single line or in the specified format as is.

```
>>> print (some operation on foo)
>>> "This is a multiline comment"
>>>
```

How do I remove of all the extra stuff.

Greater picture:
I have a module with a search function to find all functions and I want to display their descriptions along with functions

```
>>> find('*', maths) # suppose maths is a module
>>> shapes.square "This is square"
    shapes.cube   "This is cube"
```

P.S I already have the find function I just need the string to append in the print statement.

Thnaks

Comment: Try this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713138/getting-the-docstring-from-a-function

Comment: @Abe I have already tried that, however it does print out a lot of excess info which I do not want.

Comment: Well, you can just `"\n".join` the lines, but what if the docstring contains information on parameters, or even test cases?

Comment: I want to join those line. but how do I get those first. That is the question I asked?

Comment: `for obj in dir(module): print(obj.__name__, obj.__doc__.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', ''))`

Comment: Ummm, `Foo.__doc__.replace("\n", " ")`?

Comment: Though, not the solution I was looking for. But I got the drift. I think I can go ahead from here. Thanks