# i am not able to display doc string of instance of a class

Tags: python, class

```
def display():

    """ i am testing to see doc string  """
    pass

display_1=display()

print(display.__doc__)
```

output-:`i am testing to see doc string`

```
print(display_1.__doc__)
```

output-:`None`

Comment: You assign the return value of your `display()` function to `display_1`. This is None and that does not have a `doc` attribute. Do `display_1=display`

Answer (score 0):

`display_1` is not a function. It is `None` as you have taken the return value of the function `display()`

What you want to do is this:

`display_1 = display`

Do not add the `()` at the end as that will call the function and store the return value in `display_1`

Answer (score 0):

You arr calling to the function `display`, which has no return. In python, if a function returns nothing explicitly, it returns `None`.

So, when you are executing `display_1=display()`, display_1 is None, so it has not the attribute `doc`

If you want to get the docstring, call `display.__doc__`

Look at this: [Getting the docstring from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713138/getting-the-docstring-from-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

for example you can do like this also:

```
class DoubleMap(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.url = "https://someurl"

   def Method(self):
      """rejgnjknkjnklerg"""
      return self.url


mapInstance = DoubleMap.Method.__doc__
print(mapInstance)
```

in your code `display()` is no returning any value thats why you are getting none you can do like this if you want

```
def display():

    """ i am testing to see doc string  """
    return display.__doc__

display_1=display()

print(display.__doc__)
print(display_1)
```