# How to get just summary line from python docstring?

Tags: python, docstring

I write test functions. In the docstring, I usually mention test case name as the summary line. The test case description follows that. Now I just need to fetch the test case name (first line) from docstring. Is there any pythonic way to do it?

```
   def test_filesystem_001():
        """This is test case name of test_filesystem_001.

        [Test Description]
        -Create a file
        -write some data
        -delete it
        """
        pass
```

So I need a way here just to print the first line of the docstring, i.e., "This is test case name of test_filesystem_001." 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the docstring from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713138/getting-the-docstring-from-a-function)

Comment: This is clearly not duplicate of the mentioned link. This question is specific to getting summary/first line from doc string.

Comment: Yeah, but the part which isn't obvious from the duplicate is not well-defined in your question.

Comment: Anyway, I got the appropriate answer for my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just getting the first line:

```
>>>test_filesystem_001.__doc__.split("\n")[0]
This is test case name of test_filesystem_001.
```

You `split` the `__doc__` string at a new line. This returns an array of the part before the new line and the part after the new line. To access the first part use `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Take the docstring, split it into lines, and take the first.

```
print test_filesystem_001.__doc__.splitlines()[0]
```