# How to get the document of an enumeration in python

Tags: python, enums

I have plenty of files formated as follows:

```
# Content of Enumeration1.py

from enum import IntEnum

class Enumeration1(IntEnum):
    """
    Some documentation.
    """
    key_0 = 0
    key_1 = 1
    key_2 = 2
```

How can I extract the documentation using python code from another "main.py", i.e.,

```
path_to_file = "./Enumeration1.py"
doc = get_documentation(path_to_file)  # how does this function works?
print(doc)  # outputs "Some documentation."
```

Comment: Where did you get `get_documentation` from?

Comment: Do you expect to get `# Content of Enumeration1.py`, `Some documentation.` or something else? Could you import the containing module and/or load it by path, or are you restricted to extracting the documentation without running the module? Are you aware of [the `__doc__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the docstring from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713138/getting-the-docstring-from-a-function)

Comment: The `get_documentation` is the function I don't know how to implement

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I am expecting to get `Some documentation`. Unfortunately, the "Getting the docstring from a function" does not works for me as I don't know in advance the name of all the enumerations (there may be thousands).

Comment: I am looking for an automatic way to extract this documentation

Comment: What exactly are the cases you need covered? [Another comment of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75059652/how-to-get-the-document-of-an-enumeration-in-python?noredirect=1#comment132457611_75059707) implies you don't know in advance which enumerations are present; what are the searches you expect to happen? Just the top-level? Nested inside classes, nested inside functions?

Comment: Don’t cover this in comments/chat, [edit] the question to provide well-defined constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. import the module based on the path string
2. get all the variables of the module
3. restrict it to be only enums (those which are classes, subclasses of the enum classes, but not a builtin enum subclass)
4. get just the docstrings

```py
from enum import EnumType, EnumMeta, Enum, IntEnum, Flag, IntFlag, ReprEnum
import importlib.util
import inspect

def get_documentation(path_to_file, module_name):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, path_to_file)
    mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
    variables = {
        item: getattr(mod, item) for item in dir(mod) if not item.startswith("__")
    }
    enums = {
        name: value
        for name, value in variables.items()
        if inspect.isclass(value)
        and issubclass(
            value, (EnumType, EnumMeta, Enum, IntEnum, Flag, IntFlag, ReprEnum)
        )
        and value not in (EnumType, EnumMeta, Enum, IntEnum, Flag, IntFlag, ReprEnum)
    }
    docstrings = {name: value.__doc__ for name, value in enums.items()}
    return docstrings
```

For this example, the output is

```py
{'Enumeration1': '\n    Some documentation.\n    '}
```

If you want to get rid of the extra whitespace, it's as simple as adding `.strip()` after `.__doc__`

Comment: I don't know in advance which enumerations are in the file

Comment: @TheophileChampion so you want a list/dict of all the docstrings?

Comment: Yes. Idealy, if there are many enumerations in the file, I would like to get a dictionary. But the key thing is that, I don't know the name of the enumerations (i.e., there are lots of files and within each file potentially many enumerations)