Extracting a delimited block of lines from a text file
In all of my python programs I have a comment block describing the program and copyright info, followed by a version log. This block is preceded and followed by 3 single quotes. It immediately follows the shebang line.
I want to extract only the lines between the '''s in that first occurrence. I thought of egrep, sed and awk. Haven't gotten egrep to work, sed doesn't seem to fit the bill and I'm going to look at awk next.
Any thoughts?
Have been working with egrep (no solutions), sed (doesn't seem to be the right solution) investigating awk (initial investigation, maybe). No soultion found yet.
The pattern of what I want to extract is as follows in my python programs:
'''
** comment block with variable number of lines **
'''

Only want the initial comment block, no other blocks that may be included in the program.
Would like to use egrep if possible, redirecting stdout to a file with the > operator.
In plain language:
Process the file line by line discarding the lines. When the first line starting with ''' (3 single quotes) is encountered, discard that line. Output (extract) the next lines. When the next line beginning with ''' (3 single quotes) is encountered, quit processing. I am hoping there is a way to do that with egrep but, may need to write a python script to do it.

Welcome to SO! Please also share what you tried. Please read how to ask a good question on SO. And you mentioned "but, may need to write a python script to do it." so are you looking for a solution in python specifically?

see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713138/getting-the-docstring-from-a-function

This question is similar to: Extract docstring form a python file using grep or awk. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

awk '/\x27{3}/ { if(n) {exit}; n=1; next }; n' file ?? To redirect just add > otherfile to the end.

Is there a reason why you want to do this in Posix shell and not in Python?

@David C. Rankin Your awk suggestion works great thanks

awk is well worth learning. It's syntax is very close to C, and it is blistering fast. It is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. Quite simple too when you realize it simply reads a line at a time from the file, and applies the [condition - optional] { rules } you write for it -- in the order you provide. GNU Awk User's Guide is a great reference. If you are going to spend any time programming on Linux, learning awk will save you 100 times the time it takes to learn it.

Also the n alone at the end is a condition (e.g. n != 0) and a condition without a rule, applies the default rule of print. So the command just says /\x27{3}/ if there are 3 apostrophes { if n already set {you are done, exit};  otherwise set n=1; skip to next record} The next record is then the comment you want which does not have 3 apostrophes, so it hits the next [cond] { rule } which is just n and applies the default rule of print printing all your comment content. Then the next 3 apostrophes encountered triggers exit. So there are two rules :)

@David C. Rankin I have awk on my radar fot the cold days of winter. Will definitely start with your link to the User's Guide. For now I have written a a Python script for this project, with added flexibility (dynamically specifying files and delimiters). Thanks

@user1934428 I ended up writing it in Python, for the total flexibility. RE: my comment to David C. Rankin.
